# Batch Read Text From a Child Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

i plan on releasing a tool to back up gamesaves for a certian game but i am having problems with batch telling it to get its text. i get returned with Wput  but i want it to say ftp://SPECIFIED_USER_IN TEXT FILE:
Not quite sure if this is possible but i looked around(UPLOAD represents wput.exe) UPLOAD isnt the issue. the issue is telling it where to go.

```
@echo off
set /p user=./server_information/user.txt
set /p pass=./server_information/pass.txt
set /p host=./server_information/host.txt


ser world=worldname.txt
cd UploadingHandler
upload ftp://%user%:%pass@%host%:21/%world% %world%
pause
```

any help? Thanks.

edit:

if you need better understanding here is a treemap:

```
ROOT
   UploadingHandler
       epload.exe
-
   Server_Information
       Host.txt
       user.txt
       pass.txt
-
```

Comment: Excuse me. It is difficult to answer a question if we must discover first _what_ the question is. I suggest you to entirely rewrite your question in simpler terms. Put what you have with a few examples (a directory with files? A file with text?), what you want to do with that data and the expected results with a few examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SET /P` command reads input from the console unless you redirect the input to be from another device, e.g. from a file. This is done using the `<` symbol:

```
SET /P variable=prompt text < filename
```

The *`prompt text`* part is optional. So, to give you an example using one of your files:

```
set /p user=<./server_information/user.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted either, but to read a file using batch you could do this:

for %%a in (myfile.txt) do print %%a

or:
for %%a in (myfile.txt) do :adef

:adef
print %%a

Comment: You can't reference the loop variable outside the loop's context. Also, you missed the `CALL` command after `do` in your second example, and the entire command should look like `CALL :adef %%a`, if you want to use the value in the subroutine. Also, if you meant to read the file *contents* you'd need the `FOR /F` loop, not the `FOR` loop. Also, you could indent the code lines with 4 spaces to format them as code (they should also be surrounded by empty lines to be distinguished from the neighbouring paragraphs).

Comment: As you can see I'm a tad rusty with me ol' batch commands, but yes, what andriy said :)